# Multiple Class Files driven by a single SO library

Tags: java, c, linux, shared-libraries

Using `loadLibrary` (or something similar) one can support multiple native methods in a single class. Is it possible to support multiple classes with multiple native methods by the very same library?

Comment: yes it can be because the method generated in header file (generated by javah)will have signature of `lang_className_method`